# Como realizar un post ajax con jquery y symfony

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

El problema que tengo es que quiero enviar un post con ajax al presionar un botón. El código es el siguiente:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#import_btn', function() {

        $('#result').html('');
        var from = $("#from").val();
        var id = $("#imdb_id").val();

        if (from != '' && id != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  '/import_video',
                data: "id=" + encodeURIComponent(id) + "&from=" + encodeURIComponent(from),
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#import_btn").html('Fetching...');
                },
                success: function(response) {
                 // recuperar datos
                });
    });
```

En la parte de url no se que escribir para que mi enrutador me dirija al controlador y yo pueda regresar los datos, este código se encuentra en la parte de vista de mi archivo con extensión .twig.

Tengo un archivo index.php que se encarga de mapear las rutas y redigir a la vista correspondiente:

```php
$request = Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals(
    $_SERVER,
    $_GET,
    $_POST,
    $_COOKIE,
    $_FILES
);

$routerContainer = new RouterContainer();
$map = $routerContainer->getMap();

$map->post('importVideoControl', '/import_video', [
        'controller' => 'App\Controllers\importVideoController',
        'action' => 'importVideoControl'
    ]);
```

El controlador importVideoController es una clase en la cual hace el renderizado html de la plantilla twig.

Alguien me puede guiar para resolver mi problema, gracias.

Comment: en tu controlador debes tener un metodo alq ue se accede por una ruta `/**
     * @Route("/lucky/number/{max}", name="app_lucky_number")
     */`

Comment: tengo esto en mi router container: /*** $map->post('importVideoControl', '/import_video', [
        'controller' => 'App\Controllers\importVideoController',
        'action' => 'importVideoControl'
    ]); ***/